# Wi-Fi device connected, but no signals detected?

Tags: wireless, usb

I plugged in my USB wi-fi adapter. I then unplugged the ethernet cable. I expected to see a list of networks I could connect with. I saw no such networks in the connection center on the top right of the screen. I figured that my USB Wi-Fi device was not working.

lsub shows my device is connected.

However when I click on the network center, I don't see any wireless networks. The only entries listed in the network manager are "wired" and "proxy".

What should I do?

I think the wi-fi isn't installed is all. I am running Ubuntu 13.04 on my desktop.

```
> lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 13b1:0039 Linksys AE1200 802.11bgn Wireless Adapter [Broadcom BCM43235]

>lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_utf8               12493  1 
udf                    83786  1 
parport_pc             27504  0 
ppdev                  12817  0 
rfcomm                 37420  0 
bnep                   17669  2 
bluetooth             202109  10 bnep,rfcomm
ext2                   63166  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     36186  1 
nvidia               8582455  65 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    63791  1 
kvm_amd                50336  0 
kvm                   376505  1 kvm_amd
mxm_wmi                12893  0 
video                  18894  0 
wmi                    18590  1 mxm_wmi
snd_hda_intel          38307  6 
snd_hda_codec         117617  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13272  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                80890  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         14230  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            25114  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                51280  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              24411  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
asus_atk0110           17390  0 
snd                    56485  22    snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,    snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
i2c_nforce2            12876  0 
k10temp                12958  0 
mac_hid                13037  0 
lp                     13299  0 
psmouse                81065  0 
microcode              18286  0 
parport                40753  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
soundcore              12600  1 snd
serio_raw              13031  0 
hid_generic            12484  0 
usbhid                 41805  0 
hid                    82666  2 hid_generic,usbhid
pata_acpi              12886  0 
firewire_ohci          35292  0 
firewire_core          61718  1 firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t              12627  2 udf,firewire_core
forcedeth              61777  0 
pata_amd               13761  0 
ahci                   25507  3 
libahci                26108  1 ahci
```

**dmesg output**: This is really long, it takes up my whole terminal page, still want it? I don't know what I'm looking for from it.

```
 >ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:8c:79:5e:11  
          inet addr:192.168.1.218  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2602:304:cd4a:87b9:224:8cff:fe79:5e11/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::224:8cff:fe79:5e11/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4964074 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1814118 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7124764702 (7.1 GB)  TX bytes:148838056 (148.8 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:267772 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:267772 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:27839379 (27.8 MB)  TX bytes:27839379 (27.8 MB)
```

Thanks for all the help! Much appreciated.

Comment: Show the output of "dmesg" command while you connect wi-fi device. Also, see "ifconfig -a" command output - Your adapter must be in the list.

Comment: Can you please paste the relevant line of the output of `lsusb`? There seem to be multiple drivers for the same series of Broadcom devices out there and I suspect something similar to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Device/Broadcom_BCM4311_Natty_11.04

Answer (score 0):

Open the network manager in the system settings. Is there a wireless network (adapter) in the list? If yes, you may have disabled it with a hardware switch, which many laptops have as a dedicated switch or a keyboard combination. Otherwise we will have to look into possible driver problems.

Are you sure there are any wireless networks in range?

Comment: I believe I am in the network manager. My path was System Settings-> Network (I did not see network manager, but I believe this is the network manager). The options I can select are wired, and network proxy.    I am certain there are wireless networks in range.   Thank you for the help. I'm very new to Ubuntu, and am slowly taking to it, but I have alot to learn. I believe it is a driver issues.  I am also trying to see if my adaptor work/is supported, but am having trouble finding a list. Here is my adaptor:Linksys AE1200 802.11bgn Wireless Adapter [Broadcom BCM43235]
Thanks for the Help!!!!!

Comment: This is most definitely a missing driver. Please put the relevant output of `lsusb` and `lsmod` into your question.

Comment: which part of lsmod is relevant? I didn't see any module that really stood out me me, such as one called "broadcom" or linksys.

Comment: Paste all of them, if you're unsure.